# Regex to match date formats DD-MM-YYYY and DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: regex, validation, date, sublimetext3

I'm working in Sublime Text 3 with a large text file that has entries separated by lines. I'm looking for a regular expression that will:

- Match entries that appear in the `DD-MM-YYYY` format
- Match entries that appear in the `DD/MM/YYYY` format

If both would be too complicated, then just the first example will do.

I haven't done anything to work towards such a regex, because it's honestly way above my knowledge of it and I wouldn't know where to start, and looking at similar answers dealing with regex validation of date formats confirms those suspicions for me.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This pattern will work for your conditon. Strictly not allowed month to date and vice versa.

```
^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$
```

This pattern will match these formats: (Date, Month, Year)

```
25.04.2017  
02.04.2017  
2.4.2017  

25/04/2017  
5/12/2017  
15/2/2017  

25-04-2017  
6-10-2017  
16-5-2017
```

Comment: This is a good answer to a different question, but not really an answer to this one.

Comment: Beware. This will also match strings like 25/04.2017 and 25.04-2017

Comment: Although it does match 25/04.2017, the odds of someone typing that are extremely low.

Answer (score 7):

This regex matches your example:

```
[0-9]{2}[-|\/]{1}[0-9]{2}[-|\/]{1}[0-9]{4}
```

but if you write wrong date (like 31 Feb) this regex match it.

Comment: Does this not also accept `dd-mm/yyyy` and `dd/mm-yyyy`? If so, even if it may be good enough, it doesn't do what the question asked, and doesn't make any mention of that fact, so is likely to mislead readers.

Comment: There is no month restrictions it takes more than date and month value. It allows 35/31/2007 is a valid date, check out my answer which can solve the month and date range validation issue[but Feb31, Apr31, June31, Sep31, Nov31 invalid dates still not solved].

Answer (score 0):

Check This:

```
([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])[-|\/](((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))[-|\/]\d{4}
```

I think this is perfect match for your answer. It takes date upto 31, month upto 12.