# How to convert a string with extra characters

Tags: java, string, date, format, simpledateformat

How to convert a string with extra characters

String str = "file-09-01-2024"

pattern = "dd-MM-YYYY"

using SimpleDateFormat with pattern = "dd-MM-YYYY"

I don't know how many extra symbols there can be

What if the extra characters are at the end? What if you don't know where it is?
"file-09-01-2024-version1"
"09-01-2024-index"
"09-01-2024"
All we know is that the date is in the String, but we don’t know where

Comment: Split the pattern out manually (ie last 10 characters) or use a regular expression to try and find it

Comment: By all means stop using `SimpleDateFormat`. It’s a notorious troublemaker of a class and has fortunately been outdated the last 10 years. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex to extract the `dd-MM-YYYY` part.
A simple regex to match it could be `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}`. This matches 2 digits, a hyphen, 2 digits, a hyphen and then 4 digits. You can test it on regex101 : https://regex101.com/r/socnHp/1.

Example:

```
String str = "file-09-01-2024"
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}").matcher(str);
matcher.find();
String mmddyy = matcher.group(); // this gets the first substring that matches the regex
Date parsed = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(mmddyy);
```

### Note

The regex I provided will still match incorrect dates, like 09-14-2024. I believe in for your use case it's fine but if you need stricter validation, you can check similar questions on this site, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42355995/7424948).

Comment: There's no need for that and also no need to adhere to superseded and faulty date classes. All you need is `DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'file-'dd-MM-yyyy");` Not clear what the exact use case is, but one usage is `LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("file-09-01-2024", dtf);`

Comment: 1. OP clearly wrote "I don't know how many extra symbols there can be" so we do need a regex, as your solution only works for one specific use case of this exact prefix.
2. "no need to adhere to superseded and faulty date classes" -> I agree that `SimpleDateFormat` needs to be avoided, but OP asked about using it.

Comment: Sorry I missed that. In that case, something like `String prefix = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('-'));String datePat = String.format("'%s'-dd-MM-yyyy", prefix);DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePat);`

Comment: Wouldn't work with `"my-file-09-01-2024"`

Comment: Yes, it would depend on the marker, so a regex could be better, in which case, `String prefix = str.replaceAll("(.*?)\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}", $1);`

Answer (score 1):

## Substring

Use the [`String#substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) method to extract the relevant portion at the end.

```
String input = "file-09-01-2024" ;
String datePortion = input.substring( input.length() - 10 ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( datePortion , f ) ;
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/ePjeff).

Of course the ideal solution would be educating the publisher of your data to:

- Share data as properly delimited text.
- Use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats only when exchanging date-time values. For a date, that is YYYY-MM-DD.

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

> using SimpleDateFormat

Never use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, `Calendar`, etc.

These terribly flawed classes are now legacy, years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: What if the extra characters are at the end? What if you don't know where it is?
"file-09-01-2024-version1"
"09-01-2024-index"
"09-01-2024"
All we know is that the date is in the String, but we don’t know where

Comment: @Ignatyo That was not your original question.

Comment: @Ignatyo Use the regex approach from the other answer to extract the date part from the string and parse into a `LocalDate` as shown in this answer. Then you got the best of both.